# Appending an iFrame to a child window that loads local html

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.open

I'm having an issue in my javascript project where I can't get an iframe to load local html into a child window.

I have a button interface setup where when clicked it does `window.open()` and creates a bunch of html DOM elements. The window loads the iframe, but it doesn't load the iframe content. Also, if I use a remote address like `www.theuselessweb.com/` the iframe loads that just fine, but nothing in the main html's directory. Like `'projectFolder/UnityWebPlayer.html'` for example doesn't work. I know its a referencing issue because all remote content works fine when I append the iframe to the main html `<body>` but it doesn't work when appended to `window.open()`'s `<body>`.

//EDIT

So forcing the full protocol `file:///K:/ ... /projectFolder/UnityWebPlayer.html` works, but how is this going to work on a web server? How can I get relative pathing to work? I also tried `../projectFolder/UnityWebPlayer.html` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Is the project hosted on a web server or a local server or is it just using `file://` protocol?

Comment: Just `file://` for now. I do intend to host this using `github.io`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. It has to do with the URL: "about:blank". The window appears to be created in null space with nothing pointing to it. If you call `window.document.open()` after `window.open()` it will open a new window with the parent.html as the URL. Now it knows what its parent directory is. From there I can call `window.document.write()` to create the `<html>` `<body>` tags, append my DOM elements, and relative pathing works with iframes in separate windows created in JavaScript.